# How to Sync data between two components using a service

Tags: angular

I have two components that I want to sync data with.

**From user/product/product.component.ts**

**To user/carts/carts.component.ts**

In the product component I am receiving data from firebase about the price of a product

```
totalPrice;

addToCart(item, counter, totalPrice){
    this.totalPrice = this.myDocData.price * counter;
   this._backendService._fincartPriceSource.next(this.totalPrice);
}
```

The above function gets the price increases it as per the counter number and then sends it to the service

**This is my service code**

```
_fincartPriceSource = new Subject<any>();
```

**This is my cart code**

```
export class CartsComponent implements OnInit {
  cartprice="0";

  constructor(private _backendservice: BackendService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._backendservice._fincartPriceSource.subscribe(totalPrice => {
      this.cartprice = totalPrice;
    })
  }
}
```

I can console log it in the Oninit and the result shows up but when I use it in my cart.component.html file it does not.

This is my cart.component.html code where I use the "cartprice" variable

```
<h2>Checkout Page {{ cartprice }}</h2>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It can be related with change detection. Try the following:
`Promise.resolve(null).then(() => {this.cartprice = totalPrice;});`
inside the `subscribe` method

Comment: Try using RxJs Subject check this blog out http://coding-karma.com/2018/05/06/angular-5-sharing-data-components-using-rxjs-subject/

Comment: Can you provide a working stackblitz of the same?

Comment: how are these components related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components may be using a different instance of the same service. Register your service in your app.module.ts so they use the same service instance.

Comment: Thank you so much sir . I registered the service and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in service u must first create BehaviorSubject and connect to data variable like this

```
private subtotalSubject$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(this.data.subtotal);
```

next define this

```
readonly subtotal$: Observable<number> = this.subtotalSubject$.asObservable();
```

final in your component u can use this your call function with async

```
{{ cart.subtotal$|async}}
```

so all data change by cart service updated in all place used this service